# After partial matching, scanf() ignores the remainder of the input?

Tags: c, scanf

Is it an intended behavior for `scanf()`, to ignore the remainder of the input after partially matching the format string?

The source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=0, b=0;
    b = scanf("abc %d def", &a);
    printf("a=%d, b=%d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

The output (BTW, I'm using GCC 6):

> ```
> $ ./test_scanf01
> abc 123 def
> a=123, b=1
> $ ./test_scanf01
> fff 444 zzz
> a=0, b=0
> $ ./test_scanf01
> abc 333 rrrr
> a=333, b=1
> ```

Comment: There's no way to find out about mismatches after the last conversion specification (that is assigned and counted — excluding `%*d` because it is not assigned, and `%n` because it is not counted).  It's a design limitation of the `scanf()` family of functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Disagree.  `int n = 0; scanf("abc %d def%n", &a, &n); if (n) ...` is a simple way to find out about mismatches after the "last" conversion specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `scanf` reads as long as the input matches the format. Once there is a mismatch `scanf` stops reading and leaves the rest in the buffer.

For example if you have

```
scanf("%d %d", &int_var_1, &int_var_2);
```

and the input is

```
123 abc
```

then only the `"123 "` part would be read. The letters `"abc"` (and the trailing newline) would be left in the input buffer for the next input operation to read.

Comment: Hmmm, had the `scanf()` format been `"%d%d"` instead, would you expect the remainder to be `"abc\n"` or `" abc\n"`?

Comment: @chux Considering that the `%d` format skips leading space, the first (`"abc\n"`).